# How to resolve the issue "SIM card full"?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, sim-card

On my Android 4.2.2 I always get the following notification message after activating my SIM card:

> SIM card full
>
> Delete some messages to make room for...

However, when I go to the setting `Text messages on SIM card`, I receive the following information:

> No messages on the SIM card.

Moreover, `SMS storage location` is set to Phone and should thus not store any messages on my SIM card.

Aside this background, how is it possible that my SIM card is apparently full and how can I resolve the notification message?

Comment: What do you mean by "activating my SIM card"? Is not already receiving service from the carrier?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/GqwmOj3DKns

Comment: Dear @KenSharp, by "activating" I mean the unlocking of my SIM card, e.g. after boot or disabling of the airplane mode.

Comment: Dear @programming, unfortunately I cannot upgrade my OS to Android 5. Does this mean that I cannot resolve this error?

Comment: I am sure there is a way to fix it with out the upgrade

Comment: @programming please let me know if you have any ideas! Thankfully, Robert

Comment: Is it maybe somehow possible to block (suppress) this specific Android notification?